# Google App Engine Memory Limit - Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a memory limit to the Task Queue on Google App Engine.  I'm specifically concerned with the Go runtime, but it would be nice to get answers on all runtimes if someone can provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks are executed by the same app instance(s) as the regular requests, only tasks are allowed to run longer. So the same memory limits apply (also subject to the task queue specific limits and quota, which *might* also eat into the instance memory).

You might chose to direct tasks to a dedicated module to which you assign an instance class with more memory (more powerful as well), if memory consumption is a concern.

But since the max instance class memory size is currently 1G I suspect your instance will most likely hit the 'soft private memory limit' and be killed before loading a full 1G file into memory :)

Comment: I believe those reference the size of the Task object being pushed into the queue, unless I'm mistaken.  I'm more asking how much memory can be used during the Task run.  Given that there is no disk, if I pull down a 1GB file from the Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage will it cause an error?  I know the typical App Engine runtime won't allow that, but Task queue appears to have exemptions on total execution time so I'm curious if the same is true for memory.  Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Ah, I totally misinterpreted your question :)

Comment: No worries.  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A "task" is essentially represented by a URL that's stored away for later delivery to an instance of your app. The representation of a task is independent of language, unless you use a stringified, language-specific serialization of something as a value.

If by memory limit you mean "how much (where much = count*size) task queue stuff can I have pending?," the answer is spelled out in the [Task Queue section of the quotas document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Task_Queue).

If you're asking how big a single task can be, that'll depend on the memory size of your instances, since you'll need enough memory to construct a task before enquing it.

For task processing the app instances need enough memory to accept and process a task, or enough memory to accept and process many concurrently, if your app is configured to accept multiple simultaneous requests. How much memory that takes beyond accepting the URL is basically up to how the app is coded.